# Using django south with a different set of database credentials

Tags: django, postgresql, django-south

I'm building a Django app which connects to a PostgreSQL database, and the credentials that the app uses has quite limited permissions granted over the relevant tables.

I'd like to be able to use south to manage database migrations, but given that this picks up on the same credentials that Django uses, this throws an error as south cannot make any changes to tables it doesn't own.

Is there a way to specify that south should use a different set of credentials to manage migrations other than that specified by the application settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes : have another set of settings with different credentials for south migrations and use the `--settings` option when calling the `migrate` command.

NB : to avoid DRY violation, you can as well start your special settings file by importing * from the normal settings and just override the DB credentials.

Comment: So presumably I can put another settings file in my project folder called `migrationsettings.py` and then just do `--settings=migrationsettings` ?

Comment: Yes that's basically the point - except for the argument which should be something like "yourproject.migrationsettings" or something like that (ie : the Python "path" to your settings module).